# How to modify label of List View Actions?

Tags: visualforce, list-view, enhancedlist

I have created a visualforce page and I have added the Task list view there using  apex:enhancedList like this :

```
<apex:enhancedList type="Activity" height="500"  rowsPerPage="50" customizable="true" />
```

I have overwritten the "Edit" button, and I want also to edit the label of this button.

[image: Enhanced List]

Is there a way to edit the label of this button?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to change that label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stuck with Javascript hacks on this one, I think. That text can't be changed at the metadata level. That said, it's not too difficult to tweak your `<apex:enhancedList>`. Unfortunately it's slightly complicated because there is a delay before the elements get injected into the DOM. Seems to take more than 100ms but less than 200 pretty consistently, but YMMV. Simpler to set a window timeout than use mutation observers.

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:enhancedList height="400" type="Activity" />
    <script>
    (function (D, w) {
        "use strict";
        var changeLabel = function () {
            [].forEach.call(
                D.getElementsByClassName("x-grid3-col-ACTION_COLUMN"),
                function (element) {
                    element.firstChild.innerHTML = "Custom";
                }
            )
        };
        D.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            w.setTimeout(changeLabel, 200);
        });
    }(document));
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, I tried the code that you showed here in the same way. It does not work in my case.

Comment: @Jurgen "does not work" is kind of hard to help you with. Open up the Javascript console. Do you get any errors? You might need to bump up the time delay from 200.

Comment: I fix it by replacing w => window, in w.setTimeout(changeLabel, 200). Thanks for the help.